# conditional new_local_library in Bazel WORKSPACE

Tags: bazel

I've got some pre-built 3rd party libraries that I have to include in my Bazel build. So I have something like this in my `WORKSPACE`:

```
new_local_repository(
   name = "thirdparty",
   path = ".install/OSX/DEBUG",
   build_file = "bazel/BUILD.third_party",
)
```

And the `BUILD.third_party` looks like:

```
cc_library(
    name = "glog",
    srcs = ["glog/0.3.5.r1/lib/libglog.a"],
    hdrs = glob([
       "glog/0.3.5.r1/include/**"
    ]),
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
   includes = [
      "glog/0.3.5.r1/include"
   ]
)
```

The issue is that the `OSX/DEBUG` part of the `path` in the `new_local_repository` rule needs to depend on the current platform and the `compilation_mode` (e.g. I want to link in a release build of `glog` if the `compilation_mode == opt`). However, as I understanding the `new_local_repository` rule must be evaluated during the loading phase and the command line options and other configuration information isn't available at that point. Similarly `select` expressions aren't available in `WORKSPACE` files. Is there any way to do this?

## Edit

I found a way that **should** work but there appears to be a bug in Bazel. Here's my bug report: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by flipping it around: write separate `new_local_repository` rules and a `select` where they're used.

For example, two repositories in `WORKSPACE`, with the same `build_file`:

```py
new_local_repository(
   name = "thirdparty_debug",
   path = ".install/OSX/DEBUG",
   build_file = "bazel/BUILD.third_party",
)
new_local_repository(
   name = "thirdparty_release",
   path = ".install/OSX/RELEASE",
   build_file = "bazel/BUILD.third_party",
)
```

Then, use an additional "forwarding" library which depends on relevant library in the appropriate repository. Like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "glog",
    deps = select({
        "a_config_setting_for_opt": ["@thirdparty_release//:glog"],
        "//conditions:default": ["@thirdparty_debug//:glog"],
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`BUILD.third_party` could look the same as your example. It might be worth restricting the visibility to only the forwarding target's package to avoid accidental direct dependencies though.

Comment: that's a nice solution! I think it works but it's fairly cumbersome: for 3 build platforms and 2 build configurations I have to write 6 `new_local_repository` rules and a big select statement which starts to add up since we have something like 10 third-party dependencies. If this was in a `BUILD` file I could write a macro to generate all the combinations but I believe that isn't allowed in a `WORKSPACE`. Upvoting for correctness but not marking correct in hopes of getting a more elegant solution.

Comment: Actually, you can use macros in `WORKSPACE` just like a `BUILD` file. There's a different set of APIs of course (ie no `native.cc_library`, but `native.existing_rules` is commonly used). Python-style list comprehensions work too. I would definitely use some combination of those to deduplicate if you have that many.